# Why is Code Review SE still in private beta?

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase

The [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review) was supposed to go into public beta earlier today — several hours ago — but it is still marked as a private beta, and I can't post there.

When will it go public?

Comment: Could it be your time zone?

Comment: @Radek No, it's been 2 hours since the techinical launch date. Launch date was 19:00:00Z on January 19th. It is currently past 21:00:00Z on January 26th.

Comment: Strange. Maybe it needs some extra days because the number of Qs per day is worrying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The time and date for a site transition (private beta / public beta / launch) is not always going to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

Good news. The Code Review site is in public beta now so any members that are not in the private one can join now.

The Area 51 site for it says the site's progress will be evaluated in 83 days.